# Combine rows with same date and site

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

I want to move the values of the substances that have the same station ID and date on an unique row. How can I do that? maybe with `aggregate`or `match`or `merge`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to remove the NA elements and keep only the non-NA, do a grouping by summarise and get the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(station, date) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), 
    ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)), .groups = 'drop')
```

Or use a condition to return the first non-NA after grouping

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(station, date) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(),  ~if(all(is.na(.x))) NA else
          .x[!is.na(.x)][1]))
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
aggregate(.~ station + date, df1, sum, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you. I prefer keep the substances on the columns, however my real dataframe is more complex and the name of the substances does not start with 'substance': I have 266 substances with different names; the picture was just an example.  If I apply the second code you posted I get 0 instead that NA in cells that have no matches.

Comment: I don't know why it puts zero and it doesn't leave 'NA'.

Comment: @AUS85 `sum(NA, na.rm = TRUE)#[1] 0`

Comment: @AUS85 anyway, I showed multiple options.  if all of them are getting incorrect output, you may have to show a small reproducible example using `dput`

Comment: Thank you this solution worked: `df1 %>% group_by(station, date) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(),  ~if(all(is.na(.x))) NA else .x[!is.na(.x)][1]))`

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean this?

```r
library(tidyverse)

# define datasets
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~station,        ~date, ~substance1,
         1, "08/07/2009",       "5.7",
         2, "13/07/2009",         "6",
         3, "13/07/2009",       "2.2",
         4, "13/07/2009",         "2",
         5, "22/09/2009",         "1"
  )

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~station,       ~date, ~substance4,
  1, "08/07/2009",           2,
  2, "13/07/2009",           6,
  4, "13/07/2009",           3
)

# merge by station and date
full_join(df1, df2)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(station, date)`
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   station date       substance1 substance4
#>     <dbl> <chr>      <chr>           <dbl>
#> 1       1 08/07/2009 5.7                 2
#> 2       2 13/07/2009 6                   6
#> 3       3 13/07/2009 2.2                NA
#> 4       4 13/07/2009 2                   3
#> 5       5 22/09/2009 1                  NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Please be sure to include code to create the datasets and a proper description of your desired output next time.